# How to get the second utterance- Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a conversational skill in Amazon Alexa. Once I start my skill, how can I know what the user said for the second time when I set `should_end_session` as `false`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How do you mean what the user said for the second time?  Any response a user provides in a live session should match one of the utterances for your skill and those utterances are linked to intents.

What response are you trying to get from the user?  Please provide more information.